# How long is stored tap water safe to be around (not drink)?

Tags: water, expiration-dates, legionnaries-disease

I've made some makeshift exercise weights by filling old water bottles with tap water and putting them into bags. Ill never drink the water but how long is it safe to store for?

The reason I'm asking is that I've heard legionnaires' disease can be caught from shower water or car windscreen liquid if not treated. Are there any health risks (legionnaires or other) from not changing the water every so often?

Comment: As Carey Gregory mentioned, it's perfectly safe. However, if you're still concerned you can always refill some bottles with sand.

Answer (score 3):

Water stored in jugs that are never opened could contain a dozen lethal diseases and as long as you left the jugs tightly closed they would be harmless. The danger comes when water containing Legionnaires bacteria is aerosolized, such as in a shower.

So just leave the jugs closed and you can leave that water in there for years. If you really want to be certain, add a few drops of bleach to each jug. That will kill all the bacteria in the jug and as long as it remains sealed it should say that way virtually forever.